# My contours smaller than a certain value are Not being removed from list of contours, despite of correct logic. Why?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, contour

I started with this image:

[image]

Then I applied Canny Edge Detector like:

```
Mat originalMatGreyScale = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(originalPhotoMat, originalMatGreyScale, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Mat edgesMat = new Mat();
Imgproc.Canny(originalMatGreyScale, edgesMat , 50, 70);
```

I got:

[image]

Then I found a list of contours (`contours`) by `Imgproc.findContours()`.Then I did some coding to (1)find the area of largest contour (`maximumContourArea`) (2) Remove from `contours` any contour which has an area *less than* the `maximumContourArea`. Code given at the bottom of the question.

The I called `Imgproc.drawContours()` to draw **green colored** (remaining) contours on the original image by

```
for (int contourIndex = 0; contourIndex < contours.size(); contourIndex++) {
    Imgproc.drawContours(originalPhotoMat, contours, contourIndex, new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
}
```

**What I was expecting was that contours for all those little smudges and noise should be removed from the contours list `contours`, but instead I still got this Mat (with green colored contours drawn around those little smudges as well):**

[image]

**Moreover, the `Log.i()` messages in the following code print this:**

> Number of contours initially: 27
>
> Number of contours after processing: 27

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
Imgproc.findContours(edgesMap, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);


Log.i(TAG, "Number of contours initially: " + contours.size());//check

double maximumContourArea = 0;

Iterator<MatOfPoint> contoursIterator = contours.iterator();

while(contoursIterator.hasNext()) {
    MatOfPoint nextContour = contoursIterator.next();
    double nextContourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(nextContour);

    if (nextContourArea > maximumContourArea) {
        maximumContourArea = nextContourArea;
    }
}

while(contoursIterator.hasNext()) {
    MatOfPoint nextContour = contoursIterator.next();
    if (Imgproc.contourArea(nextContour) < maximumContourArea*(10 / 100)) {
        contours.remove(contours.indexOf(nextContour));
    }
}

Log.i(TAG, "Number of contours after processing: " + contours.size());//check
```

---

---

---

***EDIT:***

1. I replaced `(10/100)` by `0.1`, and actually for clarity, I have decided to rather use `0.5` for this example. This way, all contours smaller than half the area of the largest contour should be removed.
2. So after a few `Log.i` statements here and there, I had realized that the second while loop was not being executed. After some fiddling with `Iterator` and then stepping down to `foreach` loop, I was getting `ConcurrentModificationException`, so I finally found out that the solution was a `for` loop, as follows.

**PROBLEM:** (a) I still get the same `Mat`s, whereas if you look at the following code snippet and the values of `maximumContourArea` and those of `currentContourArea`s from the logcat output at the bottom of this page, you will notice that only one contour, with area of `1719.0` should remain, all others should be removed. (b) See the Logcat output after the following code.

**Code changed:**

```
Log.i(TAG, "PNM Number of contours initially: " + contours.size());//check

double maximumContourArea = 0;

for (int currentContour=0; currentContour<contours.size(); currentContour++) {
    double currentContourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(currentContour));
    if (maximumContourArea < currentContourArea) {
        maximumContourArea = currentContourArea;
    }
}

Log.i(TAG, "PNM maximumContourArea: " + maximumContourArea);//check
Log.i(TAG, "PNM maximumContourArea*.5: " + maximumContourArea*0.5);//check

for (int currentContour=0; currentContour<contours.size(); currentContour++) {
    double currentContourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(currentContour));
    Log.i(TAG, "PNM currentContourArea: " + currentContourArea);//check
    if (currentContourArea < maximumContourArea*0.5) {
        contours.remove(currentContour);
    }
}
Log.i(TAG, "PNM Number of contours after processing: " + contours.size());//check
```

**Logcat ouput:**

```
04-21 12:09:59.955: I/MainActivity(9983): PNM Number of contours initially: 27
04-21 12:09:59.957: I/MainActivity(9983): PNM maximumContourArea: 1992.0
04-21 12:09:59.957: I/MainActivity(9983): PNM maximumContourArea*.5: 996.0
04-21 12:09:59.958: I/MainActivity(9983): PNM currentContourArea: 0.0
04-21 12:09:59.958: I/MainActivity(9983): PNM currentContourArea: 0.0
04-21 12:09:59.959: I/MainActivity(9983): PNM currentContourArea: 34.0
04-21 12:09:59.959: I/MainActivity(9983): PNM currentContourArea: 40.0
04-21 12:09:59.959: I/MainActivity(9983): PNM currentContourArea: 2.5
04-21 12:09:59.959: I/MainActivity(9983): PNM currentContourArea: 0.0
04-21 12:09:59.959: I/MainActivity(9983): PNM currentContourArea: 0.0
04-21 12:09:59.960: I/MainActivity(9983): PNM currentContourArea: 0.0
04-21 12:09:59.961: I/MainActivity(9983): PNM currentContourArea: 0.5
04-21 12:09:59.961: I/MainActivity(9983): PNM currentContourArea: 1719.0
04-21 12:09:59.962: I/MainActivity(9983): PNM currentContourArea: 35.5
04-21 12:09:59.962: I/MainActivity(9983): PNM currentContourArea: 105.0
04-21 12:09:59.962: I/MainActivity(9983): PNM currentContourArea: 29.5
04-21 12:09:59.962: I/MainActivity(9983): PNM currentContourArea: 47.0
04-21 12:09:59.962: I/MainActivity(9983): PNM Number of contours after processing: 14
```

---

OK I replaced `contours.remove(currentContour);` by `Log.i(TAG, "PNM A contour with an area of " + Imgproc.contourArea(contours.remove(currentContour))
                        + " is being removed.");` because the `ArrayList`'s `remove()` method returns the thing (contour) being removed. ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)))

I also added `currentContour--;` after this statement.

Following are the Logcat messages:

```
04-21 14:15:19.824: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM Number of contours: 27
04-21 14:15:19.824: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM maximumContourArea: 1992.0
04-21 14:15:19.824: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM maximumContourArea*.5: 996.0
04-21 14:15:19.824: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 0.0
04-21 14:15:19.824: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 0.0 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.825: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 18.0
04-21 14:15:19.825: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 18.0 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.825: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 0.0
04-21 14:15:19.825: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 0.0 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.825: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 0.0
04-21 14:15:19.825: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 0.0 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.825: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 34.0
04-21 14:15:19.825: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 34.0 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.825: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 0.0
04-21 14:15:19.825: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 0.0 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.825: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 40.0
04-21 14:15:19.825: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 40.0 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.825: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 0.0
04-21 14:15:19.825: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 0.0 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.825: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 2.5
04-21 14:15:19.825: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 2.5 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 4.0
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 4.0 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 0.0
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 0.0 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 0.5
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 0.5 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 0.0
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 0.0 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 32.5
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 32.5 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 0.0
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 0.0 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 0.0
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 0.0 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 0.5
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 0.5 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 11.5
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 11.5 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 1719.0
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 35.5
04-21 14:15:19.826: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 35.5 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.827: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 59.0
04-21 14:15:19.827: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 59.0 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.827: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 105.0
04-21 14:15:19.827: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 105.0 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.827: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 1992.0
04-21 14:15:19.827: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 29.5
04-21 14:15:19.827: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 29.5 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.827: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 259.5
04-21 14:15:19.827: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 259.5 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.827: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 47.0
04-21 14:15:19.827: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 47.0 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.827: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM currentContourArea: 38.0
04-21 14:15:19.827: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM A contour with an area of 38.0 is being removed.
04-21 14:15:19.827: I/MainActivity(11125): PNM Number of contours after processing: 2
```

^ seems to be working. **THE ONLY PROBLEM THAT REMAINS NOW IS THAT why am I getting all the all the contours drawn (even those wround those lil smudges) when the last `drawContours()` is executed to draw the green colored contours on the original image.**

Comment: is `10 / 100` equal to zero? I'm not sure how Java handles this, so please try `maximumContourArea*0.1` instead. And please try differenct thresholds like `maximumContourArea*0.9` too.

Comment: Actually what @Micka says is right, 10/100 will yield 0. Either use directly 0.1 or use 10.0 / 100.0.

Comment: @api55 Yeah he was right. I corrected that, but the result is still confusing. Posted an edit in the question.

Comment: @Micka Yes, my bad, `10/100` is zero. I corrected that, but the result is still not correct. I just posted an edit in the question about it.

Comment: Not enough to time to fully read your code, but I remember when I did this I used sequential dilate and erode filters to plug up gaps in the canny/contours results... You lose 'information', but do so intelligently, so it's a net goodly.

Comment: can you log some message before `contours.remove(currentContour);`? Are you sure that `.remove` works the way you want? Maybe you have to insert an index position there instead of the element? (sorry, no idea about Java structures)

Comment: Actually 2 contours should remain the one with area 1992 and the one with area 1719 :)

Comment: @api55 1992 is the `maximumContourArea`. @Micka OK just going to do that

Comment: @Solace Exactly, but since you are not removing that one, you should have bot. @Micka `currentContour` is an index not the contour per se

Comment: @Micka Did that. See edit.

Comment: can you output contour size right before drawing the contours, again?

Comment: If `contours.size()` gave you 2 (judging by the logs) it is impossible for it to draw more things... You may be using an outdated list (one without removing things) or you are using an image that you draw before on it... to know if it is one of this two, you should do. 1) print the size of the array before the drawing part  and 2) show the image before drawing on it. If 1) gave you a number different than two then the problem is the array. If 2) gives you an image with the contours drawn then it is a used image that you have drawn on it before

Comment: you could try to draw in a different color to see whether you're working on an image that you accidentally have drawn all the contours on before (for testing or sth)

Comment: @Micka @api55 Drawing on a newly created `Mat` solved the problem =) But just for clarification, even the word `originalPhotoMat` has Not occured anywhere between `Imgproc.cvtColor(originalPhotoMat, originalMatGreyScale, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);` and `Imgproc.drawContours(originalPhotoMat, contours, contourIndex, new Scalar(0, 255, 0));` (both statements given in question) in my code.

Comment: Thank you so, so very much to both of you. I never want to make those mistakes but I still make them.

Answer (score 2):

The logic in your loop is flawed...

lets say you have an array of 10 elements, and you found out that your second element will be removed, at this moment your `currentContour` variable is 1 and you remove this element. Then you will have 9 elements, your iteration is over and you will have your `currentContour` variable in 2. What is the problem so far, when you removed your element with index 1, the element with index 2 had its index changed to 1. So, this element will never be checked, because your `currentContour` variable is already in 2.

One way of fixing this is to either create a new array and add the contours you want to have... or after removing an element change the index to the previous number `currentContour--;`